# Python Remove 2nd item from List within List

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list in the following format:

```
[[[u'Hot Dogs', u'hotdog'], [u'Food Stands', u'foodstands']], [[u'Scandinavian',       u'scandinavian'], [u'Breakfast & Brunch', u'breakfast_brunch'], [u'Coffee & Tea', u'coffee']],    [[u'Burgers', u'burgers']]]
```

I would like to remove the first item from each list (it is just a duplicate of the 2nd) and then return a simple list of these individual tags, rather than being enclosed in mutiple []. How would I go about doing this?

Edit: I would like to return a list of lists with each line representing the 2nd tag in each list as mentioned below

Comment: Do all lists contained in the list have two elements?

Comment: yes they do @StefanoSanfilippo

Comment: @zero323: what is the difference between what you write and a simple list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
rawList = [[[u'Hot Dogs', u'hotdog'], [u'Food Stands', u'foodstands']], [[u'Scandinavian',       u'scandinavian'], [u'Breakfast & Brunch', u'breakfast_brunch'], [u'Coffee & Tea', u'coffee']],    [[u'Burgers', u'burgers']]]
finalList = []

for l in rawList:
    finalList.append([i[0] for i in l])
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[[u'Hot Dogs', u'Food Stands'], [u'Scandinavian', u'Breakfast & Brunch', u'Coffee & Tea'], [u'Burgers']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do in easy way using [list comprehesion](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
[y[1] for x in l for y in x]
```

where `l` is the list that you specified.

Comment: This gives me a list of all of them, I think I was a little unclear in my question I would like to have a list of lists like so:

[hotdog, foodstands]

[scandinavian, breakfast_brunch, coffee]

Comment: Maybe you need this? [[y[1]] for x in l for y in x]. But what you are trying to do is not quite simple, so think it again.

Comment: That is really unclear! So you have this list [[1,11],[2,22], [3,33], [4,44] [5,55]]. So what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: @Tengis That is not like the list the OP has. It is like this [[[1, 11], [2, 22]], [[3, 33], [4, 44], [5, 55]], [[6, 66]]]